# Cycle count and number of instructions, assembly programming on MSP430

Tags: assembly, encryption, instructions, cpu-cycles

I have an assembly program written for MSP430 which does the following:

1. Load into memory - Plain Text
2. Load into memory - Key
3. Encrypt the Plain-Text using the Key

Now I want to calculate the number of cycles and instructions it takes to perform just the encryption. How can I go about this? The encryption algorithm is pretty complex and not a one for which I can calculate the number of cycles off the back of a scratch paper.

I can provide any other information if need be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you need is the diff of clock count value before & after step #3. Right?